# Prestashop how to know when a new user makes register in the store

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using prestashop 1.6. I wanted to know how can I get to know when some user makes register in the store? Is there any kind of hook or something like that? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable.
 Thanks

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks says, _“You can get a full list of the hooks available in PrestaShop 1.6 in the "Hooks in PrestaShop 1.6" chapter of the Developer Guide”_ – but I can’t find where that page is supposed to be. http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.5 however lists a hook `actionCustomerAccountAdd`, “Called when a new customer successfully creates account” – so I’d try and see if that still exists in 1.6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there's an hook and it's called right after a customer has been succesfully registered to the website. 
The hook name is `actionCustomerAccountAdd`, that you can call in your custom module by the `function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd($params){ ... }`, and registering it by `$this->registerHook('actionCustomerAccountAdd')`

the code of the hook is found inside the AuthController :

```
    Hook::exec('actionCustomerAccountAdd', array(
                        '_POST' => $_POST,
                        'newCustomer' => $customer
                    ));
```

as you can see you have access to the full $_POST of the registration form + the new customer object created with it.
If you need an example on how to use the hook you can see the code of the blocknewsletter module, it uses an actionCustomerAccountAdd hook, right as you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You will be informed in admin panel. Left top corner. User icon -> when new customer will be registred this icon will have number of registred user 1, 2, 120. Click to user icon to clean counter